# sql: ODBC Reserved Keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named level in my mysql database. 
I am trying to write an sql statment and one of the parameters is level of course. But I get an error. I know it's because I am using a protected word so how can I still use it in my statement. Do I put it inside commas or something?

Comment: Use backticks to enclose reserved word ``

Comment: You should avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers

Comment: ``level`` = '6'     But it still doesn't let me.

Comment: Ah the backticks didn't show up in my comment. I put them before and after. Strawberry - I know but I'm not going to change the column name now as it would mess with my front end.

Comment: post the sql statement that you are writing

Comment: SELECT u.ck_id,u.firstname, u.lastname, sc.class_description, s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(correct) FROM game_statistics gs INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = gs.user_id INNER JOIN school_classes sc ON sc.id = u.class_id INNER JOIN schools s ON s.id = sc.school_id WHERE game_type = 'exammultiple' AND gs.created_at >= '2018-03-01' AND time >='40' 
AND `level` = '6' GROUP BY user_id ORDER By name ASC, class_description ASC

Comment: I used double backticks and that didn't work. Then I used a single bakctick before and after the keyword and that almost worked and I got the error: #1052 - Column 'level' in where clause is ambiguous. By the way what I posted - you cant see the backticks for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments

## 1052 - Column 'level' in where clause is ambiguous

The above error message is telling that more than one table has column named level and so you have to prefix level column with table alias of the table whose column level you want to compare in WHERE clause. In below query I am assuming you want `schools` table `level` column so use it like this **s.level**

```
SELECT u.ck_id,u.firstname, u.lastname, sc.class_description, 
       s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(correct) 
FROM game_statistics gs 
INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = gs.user_id 
INNER JOIN school_classes sc ON sc.id = u.class_id 
INNER JOIN schools s ON s.id = sc.school_id 
WHERE game_type = 'exammultiple' AND gs.created_at >= '2018-03-01' 
      AND time >='40' AND s.`level` = '6' 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER By name ASC, class_description ASC
```

You can change to correct table alias as intended by you.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks. WHERE do I accept your answer? I can't see an accept button. Found it ´the arrows BUT it won't lt me vote. Thanks.